# cannot resolve method error for method practicing

Tags: java

```
public class MainForm {
    String varpass = "This is a string that has to be passed.";
    public String t1(){
        String text = "This is a non-static method being called.";
        return text;
    }
    public static String t2(){
        String text = "This is a static method being called.";
        return text;
    }
    public void t3(){
        System.out.println("This is a non-static void method and cannot return.");
    }
    public static void t4(){
        System.out.println("This is a static void method and cannot return.");
    }
    public void place1 (){
        //=======================================Method calls from another class========================================
        //Calls from another class. It is non-static and thus requires it to be instantiated. EG. class var = new class();
        Methods call = new Methods();
        System.out.println(call.t1());

        //Calls from another class. It is non-static void and thus requires it to be instantiated and be called straight.
        call.t3();

        //Calls from another class. It is static and thus does not require it to be instantiated. EG. class var = new class();
        System.out.println(Methods.t2());

        //Calls from another class. It is static void and thus does not require it to be instantiated.
        Methods.t4();

        //Trying to call a variable that was sent.
        Methods.getvar(varpass);
        call.getvar(varpass);

        //=======================================Method calls from current class========================================
        MainForm mcall = new MainForm();
        //Calls from within the same class. It is static and thus does not require it to be instantiated. EG. class var = new class();
        System.out.println(mcall.t1());
        mcall.t3();
        System.out.println(t2());
        t4();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainForm place = new MainForm();
        place.place1();
    }
}

public class Methods {
    String var1 = "This is a public String variable";
    String getVar = "Initial";
    public String t1(){
        String text = "This is a non-static method being called.";
        return text;
    }
    public static String t2(){
        String text = "This is a static method being called.";
        return text;
    }
    public void t3(){
        System.out.println("This is a non-static void method and cannot return.");
    }
    public static void t4(){
        System.out.println("This is a static void method and cannot return.");
    }
    public void getvar(String varsent){
        String msg = "getver() Variables are varsent("+varsent+"), getVar("+getVar+"), getVar(";
        getVar = varsent;
        msg = msg + getVar+")";
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
```

Here is the errors below

```
Methods.getvar(varpass);
call.getvar(varpass);
```

top one is giving non-static cannot be referenced from a static context

bottom one is saying cannot resolve method 'println(void)'

You can tell im using this as practice to call methods.

Here im trying to pass a variable varpass that contains a string. I want it pass that variable to getvar in Methods. in that getvar it takes a variable in Methods displays it before altering it then again after alter.

Im trying to understand how this works. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
Methods.getvar(varpass);
```

is a static call. You try to call the static Method getvar from your Methods class. This method however is not static and therefor requires an instance of Method.

This line

```
call.getvar(varpass);
```

works fine. It in fact is the solution to the first line, where you reffere a non-static method from a static context

Answer (score 0):

You cannot refer to a non-static variable/field from a static method, because a non-static field may vary between instances of a class. To solve it, make varpass `static`:

```
static String varpass = "This is a string that has to be passed.";
```

The second error results from the definition of getvar:

```
public void getvar(String varsent);
```

Since it does not return anything, it cannot be used in a `System.out.println()` as there is no definition of `println` accepting void (It doesn't know what to print).

Also, `Methods.getvar(varpass)` should be `Methods.getvar(MainForm.varpass)`, because there is no local variable with that name.

Comment: did not work. i realized that i was using system.print 2x in both classes.

Comment: @BTCDude could you edit your question to add the necessary changes?

Comment: editted.Now when i try to call it in methods with call.getvar(varpass); the getVar isnt saved when called within methods

Comment: @BTCDude You're redeclaring `msg` on every function call. Hence the previous contents are always erased when the function ends

Comment: im not getting msg. im getting the updated "getVar". Default for this var is "Initial". When i run the method it should update getVar ti whatever value is passed on. How can i maintain that variable outside of the method?

Comment: @BTCDude You'll have to assign to the class' definition of getVar. Something like `this.getVar = varsent;`